# JMeter and Junit sampler giving error 'JUnitSampler: Trying to find constructor with one String parameter returned error'

Tags: jmeter-plugins

I am using Jmeter for my Webdriver scripts.  I have following-

[image]

why is it giving this error? The script runs fine in Eclipse

Answer (score 0):

Don't care about this log.

It tried to load the String parameter constructor, when it failed, it would load the other contructor, which is the empty constructor.

write a system out example, run it, the sys out msg would print out to window command console.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lH0PY.png)